# What would result in Context.checkPermission() being called when launching activities?

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

I've got a released app which is crashing on a customer's device (but which I can't reproduce myself).

They provided me with some log info:

```
05-17 16:56:34.884 31256 31256 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.aaa.bbb/com.aaa.ccc.activity.UserLaunch}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.content.Context.checkPermission(java.lang.String, int, int)' on a null object reference
05-17 16:56:34.884 31256 31256 E AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2434)
05-17 16:56:34.884 31256 31256 E AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2494)
05-17 16:56:34.884 31256 31256 E AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:157)
05-17 16:56:34.884 31256 31256 E AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1356)
05-17 16:56:34.884 31256 31256 E AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-17 16:56:34.884 31256 31256 E AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
05-17 16:56:34.884 31256 31256 E AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5551)
05-17 16:56:34.884 31256 31256 E AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
05-17 16:56:34.884 31256 31256 E AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
```

However the UserLaunch activity doesn't call checkPermission(), and in fact nothing anywhere calls checkPermission(). 
Therefore I was wondering if there are other things that would result in checkPermission() being called indirectly?

Would a call to checkSelfPermission() result in an indirect call to checkPermission()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

checkSelfPermission() internally called the method check permission. please make sure to pass the current Activity reference to the CheckSelfPermision. like UserLaunch.this